# How do I convert bit to string in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, binary

I have a bit field in a table and the data in the field looks like '0100' or '1100', etc. It is just a string of 1's and 0's. The type of the field in MySQL is 'BIT'. I need to read the data as a string. So I simply need to say:

```
select bit_field from mytable
```

but I need the bit field to come back as a string so I have tried

```
select CAST(bit as text) from mytable
```

but that throws an error. Also

```
select Convert(bit_field as UTF8) from mytable
```

returns the wrong type of data.

How can I accomplish this so that it returns bit_field as a string of text that looks like "0101" (or whatever is in the field)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use the [export_set()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_export-set) function:

```
select export_set(bit_field,'1','0','',4) from mytable
```

Comment: Excellent. Just what I needed. Thanks.